# Why does man have its own user?

Tags: man

I'm simply curious as to why `man` has its own user.

```
$ grep man /etc/passwd
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I'm using Debian Buster.

Comment: man pages and man cache owned by man means you can use various *user accounting* tools and see how much disk space is used by man pages - for example

Comment: @Bravo are man *pages* owned by `man` on your system?

Comment: @StephenKitt - no, but `/var/cache/man` is - interesting, never noticed that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`man` (at least, [the version implemented in `man-db`](https://www.nongnu.org/man-db/)) can be set up with its own user so that its “cache” (which includes indexes, as used *e.g.* by `whatis`) can be owned and updated by that user (instead of `root`).

Additionally, `man` can be setuid to that user, allowing it to write to its cache directory without requiring specific permissions for users:

```
$ ls -ld /var/cache/man /usr/bin/man
-rwsr-sr-x  1 man man 115600 Feb 19  2021 /usr/bin/man
drwxr-xr-x 31 man man   4096 Nov 23 00:00 /var/cache/man
```

The above shows that the `man` binary is setuid and setgid `man`, and `man` owns `/var/cache/man`.

In Debian derivatives this can be configured with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure man-db`. The explanation given there is

> The man and mandb program can be installed with the set-user-id bit set, so
> that they will run with the permissions of the 'man' user. This allows
> ordinary users to benefit from the caching of preformatted manual pages
> ('cat pages'), which may aid performance on slower machines.
>
> Cached man pages only work if you are using an 80-column terminal, to avoid
> one user causing cat pages to be saved at widths that would be inconvenient
> for other users. If you use a wide terminal, you can force man pages to be
> formatted to 80 columns anyway by setting MANWIDTH=80.
>
> Enabling this feature may be a security risk, so it is disabled by default.
> If in doubt, you should leave it disabled.

“cat pages” aren’t useful nowadays, so configuring a system without support for them won’t cause any issues. It is also possible to support cat pages without allowing their creation by arbitrary users, and thus requiring a `man` user and setuid binary; various Unix systems used to be set up so that they would periodically generate *all* missing cat pages (see `catman`).

Even without a setuid `man`, a `man` user can be useful for `man`-related cron jobs (`whatis` indexes etc.).

Comment: Thank you,, Stephen. How about on systems that don't have `/var/cache/man`? (BSD,OSX)

Comment: @Jim do they have a `man` user? I don’t see one in OpenBSD, I don’t have access to a Mac to check there.

Comment: You're right, my OSX machine doesn't, but FreeBSD does, UID 9 `man:*:9:9:Mister Man Pages:/usr/share/man:/usr/sbin/nologin`

Comment: @Jim in FreeBSD, the `man` user was used [for `catman`](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/commit/?id=4572fb3faf80473e4dbb13dc956386c27cb2ad00); I don’t know whether it’s still useful nowadays. (System users tend to linger long after they cease being relevant, to avoid id re-use and ensure that old files on upgraded systems still have a meaningful owner.)

Comment: @StephenKitt: Finally an explanation why a user where I would have used a group.

Comment: @Joshua yup, groups work well if you want to allow changes to pre-existing files, not so much when creating new ones which shouldn’t be owned by whoever caused them to be created! (`man-db` actually supports the latter, if you want cat pages but don’t mind having them owned by `joerandomuser`.)